# Can't seem to access a JSON-value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, alert

I'm currently having some trouble with accessing JSON-values through the jQuery AJAX-function. The first alert works fine, but I get an "undefined" alert with the second value: this.dateOfBirth2.

It seems I can only access values which are stored in another object. Pretty weird. Any idea how I can access this.dateOfBirth2 this way?

Here's the JS-fiddle. It doesn't work, but just imagine `/js/formdata.js` is the `<script>` code above. http://jsfiddle.net/LMSmp/1/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/js/formdata.js',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        var formData = $(data.formdata);
        formData.each(function () {
          alert(this.name.surname);
          alert(this.dateOfBirth2);
        });
      }
    })
});​
```

JSON:

```
{
  "formdata": {
    "name": {
      "salutation": "Dhr",
      "surname": "Jan",
      "tussenvoegsel": "van",
      "lastName": "Boden"
    },
    "dateOfBirth1": 1,
    "dateOfBirth2": 3,
    "dateOfBirth3": 2,
    "nationality": "Nederland",
    "address": {
      "zipcode": "1234AF",
      "houseNumber": 5,
      "suffix": "",
      "street": "Kerkstraat",
      "living": "Amstelveen",
      "country": "Nederland"
    },
    "contact": {
      "homeTel": "0123-456789",
      "mobileTel": "01-23456789",
      "email":"me@mail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a fiddle where it makes sense. Here it does not and it is much more helpful (always!) to include the information in your question.

Comment: It seems to work fine here btw: http://jsfiddle.net/d4tp8/

Comment: Does the first alert actually work? The JSON string in the fiddle is invalid JSON (it has `<script></script>` tags). The JSON string in the question works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an object to jQuery, which does not make sense. jQuery is for working with **DOM elements**. [Although it might "work"](http://jsfiddle.net/d4tp8/), better use use [`$.each()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(data, function () {
    alert(this.name.surname);
    alert(this.dateOfBirth2);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ULc6h/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/js/formdata.js',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {        
          alert(data.formdata.name.surname);
          alert(data.formdata.dateOfBirth2);
      }
    });
});​
```